# Transitioning from post into game audio

Tags: audio, video-games, gameaudio, app

I'm a sound designer currently working in audio post and I'm interested in getting into working more in non-linear projects. I've worked on a game and a couple of apps but just on the sound fx and not any of the implementation.

If anyone can recommend any good resources on what extra skills/programs would be good for me to learn initially and any websites/forums/events(in the uk) that'd be good a place to meet indie game/app devs it'd much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would start off by learning wwise. Audiokinetic has a lot of tutorials and sample projects available. Beyond that, I would download Unity or UE4 and start following tutorials on implementation. Knowing how game audio works and is implemented will help you begin to sound design for the game and the players experience. Further, when you are playing games, pay attention to how the audio is working instead of focusing on how it sounds. Listen for attenuation of distance, how audio is triggered, transitions between areas, variation in sounds, etc...

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wwise is great but you may want to look into FMOD as well, as it uses a DAW-like approach. WWise's GUI is really an acquired taste... all grey with options everywhere... They really need these tutorials.